# How do I add a separate function for average calculation?

Tags: python, string, file, exception, average

I am stuck on this problem. Code I have so far works but my Professor wants to see some changes. I need to add error handing and I need a separate function for calculating average which I will call in main. Here is the what I have so far...

```
import os

def process_file(filename):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    f.close()

    scores = []

    for line in lines:
        parsed = line.split(",")
        count = int(parsed[1])
        scores.append(count)

    calculate_result(scores)

def calculate_result(scores):
    print("High: ", max(scores))
    print("Low: ", min(scores))
    print("Average: ", sum(scores)/len(scores))


def main():
    filename = "scores.text"
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        process_file(filename)
    else:
        print ("File does not exist")
        return 0


main()
```

Comment: which part are you actually stuck on? Those are pretty concrete instructions, is there some part that you are having a hard time with?

Comment: `def average(lst): return sum(lst)/len(lst)` Then `print("Average: ", average(scores))`

Comment: So if I get rid of the whole calculate_result function and replace it with calculate_average(scores). Then call it in main(). would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 2 parts:

> I need to add error handling

and

> I need a separate function for calculating average which I will call in main

The second part I don't think you need help with. But error handling is kind of an art, so I can see where you might be stuck on that. Here are some suggestions to help get started.

The most common type of error handling involves dealing with input. Thinking more broadly, we could expand that to *anything that crosses the boundary of the programs memory space*. This includes not just user input, but also output; filesystem interaction; using network interfaces (or any communication device or hardware interface); starting/stopping or otherwise interacting with other programs; calling a library that does any of these things on our behalf; and many more....

So what parts of your program are interacting with "the outside" ? I can see a few:

1. in `main()` the program is making an assumption about the existence of a file. You are already checking to make sure this file exists, and returning `0` if it doesn't (you might want to change that to a non-zero value, since `0` is usually used to signal that no error occurred)
2. `process_file()` does this: `f = open(filename,'r')` but are you sure that will work? Are there conditions where this could fail?

   - What if the user that is running the program doesn't have permissions to read that file?
   - What if the file was deleted or changed between the time it was checked in `main` and the subsequent `open` call in `process_file`? This is a [TOCTOU race condition](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO45-C.+Avoid+TOCTOU+race+conditions+while+accessing+files), and it is something that every software developer needs to watch out for.
3. Probably the most obvious source of potential errors for this program is the content of the input file:

   - We're assuming the input is comma-separated. What if the user uses tabs or some other character?
   - While processing the lines, you've got: `count = int(parsed[1])`, but how do you know that `parsed[1]` can be cast to an `int`?
   - What will happen if the file exists, but is empty (hint: `len(scores)==0`)? Always look at these edge cases.

Finally, it looks like you are using `if-then` statements for error checking. That is fine, but another powerful tool for dealing with errors are `try-except` statements. They are not mutually exclusive: sometimes it's easier to use an `if` statement, and sometimes catching an exception with `try-except` is better. Some of the errors you'll need to deal with are easier to handle using one approach over the other.